# Notifications on iOS for new questions in selected tags

Tags: support, tags, notifications, mobile-app, ios

Is there a way to get notified on an iOS device for new questions in selected tags ? 
There are some tags where a new question comes in every couple of hours. For them, I would like to be notified as soon as a new question arrives.  (This would not be useful for a high traffic tag like java etc)

Fast notifications have been discussed before in [q1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326739/auto-notifications-for-new-questions-in-stack-overflow), [q2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200015/is-there-a-faster-way-to-get-notified-of-new-questions-than-rss) or [q3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68334/what-is-the-fastest-most-efficient-way-to-get-alerts-for-stack-overflow-feeds). Mobile notifications are not discussed there. The suggested [stacksguru](https://stackapps.com/questions/345/stacksguru-a-near-realtime-bot-for-all-stack-exchange-sites) app is not for mobile as far as I see.

Answer (score 1):

What probably works (I haven't tested it) is to combine an RSS feed like this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=html&sort=newest

with an iOS app from the App Store which sends push notifications based on changes in an RSS feed, like [Newsify](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/newsify-your-news-blog-rss-feed-reader/id510153374?mt=8) or another one listed [here](https://www.igeeksblog.com/best-rss-reader-apps-for-iphone-ipad/).

Comment: The challenge in this was to find an inexpensive rss reader with push notifications. These posts mention some. [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/43qaop/is_there_an_rss_reader_with_push_notifications/) [quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-RSS-reader-that-supports-push-notification)  [xda](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/rss-reader-push-notifications-t3306239) [macrumors](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/rss-reader-with-push-notifications.1310951/). At the end I still could not find a free rss reader with push notifications.

Comment: After some struggling still could not find a good RSS reader with push notifications. Ended up asking this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/295341/looking-for-a-free-rss-reader-with-push-notifications). FYI

Comment: We don't do shopping recommendations on Ask Different. Because you're question is reasonably scoped, I've moved it over to Software Recommendations. You'll need to create an account there first, but afterwards you can take a look at their [guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) to edit your question in an even better shape.